# ignore matched production in yacc

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc

While using GNU bison, is it possible to do nothing after matching a production, and then check if some other rule can be used to reduce the same sequence of tokens? Basically, what i am looking for is similar to this:

```
iexpr: VARIABLE { if (condition) {
                    /*some action */
                  }
                  else {
                    /*pushback read symbol, and check if other pattern can
                         be matched */
                  }
                }
 fexpr: VARIABLE {   }
```

Thanks

Comment: I am curious to know how you ended up having this requirement. I am not aware of such facility with bison. If control is executing your code that means bison has already matched the pattern for you. Even if you somehow hack it and try to achieve your goal, bison will end up matching the same rule for next iteration. I would suggest defining grammar properly. I might be able to help you if you tell what you are parsing.

Comment: @AshishMahamuni: I basically agree with your assessment. I can't answer for the OP, but one context where something similar might be useful is in a verbose language (SQL) where you want to allow keywords to be used as identifiers.  I've seen things rigged so that when an error is detected, if the token is currently a keyword, the syntax was retried with a token type of IDENTIFIER instead of the keyword.  That works surprisingly well; there are still a few places where you run into trouble with it.

Comment: Correct terminology please. These are *productions,* not 'patterns'.

Comment: @AshishMahamuni am trying to create an interpreter with strict typing. So, integer expressions (iexpr) and float expressions (fexpr) can both be derived from variables, depending on the type of the variable.

Comment: You can't express type in a grammar and you shouldn't try. Grammar is for syntax only. The Algol-68 project was the last time typing in the grammar was attempted and it ended in a famous fiasco.

Comment: @EJP So what is your suggestion for a strongly typed language?

Comment: re-entrant parser will solve the problem. see http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/reentrantparser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this with [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/) -- a yacc variant that does backtracking:

```
iexpr: VARIABLE [ if (!condition)
                     /* this parse was wrong, backtrack and try something else */
                    YYERROR; ]
                { /* some action */ }
fexpr: VARIABLE { /* some other action */  }
```

but as commenters have noted, trying to do typechecking in the parser is a bad idea and just leads to a needlessly complex grammar and bad, confusing error messages for type errors.

Instead, just have single (set of) `expr` rules for expressions of all types and do typechecking in a separate pass over the resulting parse tree.  You don't even need to build the entire parse tree and keep it around for this; you can build little pieces of the parse tree and typecheck them immediately, then throw away unneeded info before further parsing.  Something like:

```
expr: expr '+' expr {
    Typecheck('+', $1, $3); /* make sure operand types are appropriate for an add */
    $$ = BuildBinopCode('+', $1, $2); /* build some code to add two things */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the YYBACKUP feature for this.

Comment: how to? example?